# jsp fullcalendar select: not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

the `select:` of the fullcalendar code looks like this;

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
if (start.isBefore(moment())) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
  return false;
} else {
  //ajax Call to fill the Updated values in Modal Form
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getRequestBookingModalData.jsp?hallID=" + hallNameselected,
      sucess: function(data) {
        window.alert("Hi Success");
        $('#modal_bookingDetails').html(data);
        $('#bookingRequestModal').modal("show");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log("jqXHR );
        }
      });
    //$('#bookingRequestModal').modal("show") ;
  }
},
```

The above ajax call is not working. The URL jsp just returns a string to be included in `modal-body`. The `html` code of `Modal body` looks like this

`<div class="modal-body" style="max-height: calc(100vh - 200px); overflow-y: auto;" name="modal_bookingDetails" id="modal_bookingDetails"></div>`

The `getRequestBookingModalData.jsp` is working fine as I can see the output through `System.out.println`. Also, the Chrome Console shows this message of success `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3049 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/chbs/bookHall/getRequestBookingModalData.jsp?hallID=1"`. So problem appears to be in js/ajax code in the `select:`.

Please advise as to why the `select:` is not working on mouse click on any `Valid` Day Range?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Seems you can't add an ajax() function inside fullcalendar js coding. So I tried this it worked smooth

```
function showModal(data){
     window.alert("Hi Success");
     $('#modal_bookingDetails').html(data);
     $('#bookingRequestModal').modal('show');
 };


$.ajax({ //ajax Call to fill the Updated values in Modal Form
  async: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'getRequestBookingModalData.jsp?hallID=' + hallNameselected,
  success: function(data) {
    showModal(data);
},
```

I am using `async: false,` because I want to wait till all data being sought from database is completed before displaying the `modal`. I know, it is against the spirit of `ajax` which means `asynchronous` but I need it this way.

Comment: "need it this way". No you don't...your modal won't be shown until "showModal" is called, and showModal is called inside your "success" function, which won't run until the ajax call completed - this is true even when async is set to true. Besides, async:false is deprecated (you'll get a console warning in some browsers) and you can expect it to stop working in future, so don't design anything around the assumption you can use it.

Comment: Oh... Thank You. I had trouble at different chunk of code where I needed to have `asyn: false` to get the name from the database. I will try what you are suggesting. Thanks again